# immutability-helper not updating state

Tags: reactjs, immutability

This is pretty straightforward, but react is not updating the state when I am finished with setState. I am consoling out my values and newState is changed, but when I call this.state it holds old values.

```
let newState = update(this.state, {newItem: {$apply: function(x) {return x +1;}}, isEditing:{$set:false}, displayArray:{$push: [newObj]}});
this.setState(newState);
console.log("newState::",newState);
//{displayText: "newBook", displayArray: Array(4), isEditing: false, newItem: 1, isEditingAll: false, …}
console.log(this.state);
//{displayText: "newBook", displayArray: Array(3), isEditing: true, newItem: 0, isEditingAll: false, …}
```

Comment: There is no assurance that setState will resolve immediately. To run your test, try using setState with a callback as second argument. See https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate

Answer (score 0):

I found out the problem, I was setting the state of the array to props that were coming in during componentWillReceiveProps. So my state was updating and then updating again back to the props value. I need to figure out a way to stop copying from props.